# Rails + Phusion Passenger + AWS RDS + AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I am trying to deploy a Rails application to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk and AWS RDS as my database. I have done all the required configuration, entered all the required Database connectivity details.

Now I am stuck because of one error, which I cannot find a solution for.

```
(erb):40: unknown regexp options - yql (SyntaxError)
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/erb.rb:849:in `eval'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/erb.rb:849:in `result'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:99:in `database_configuration'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:128:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:319:in `before_handling_requests'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:136:in `negotiate_spawn_command'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:160:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I am absolutely clueless how to solve this. I have to complete this by tomorrow and submit it since it is my project… Please help!!!

Comment: Does your application run locally?  Or do you get the same error?